# Choosing right tool

Tags: data-integration

I have following need:

1) Users will upload .xls or .csv files in "uploads" folder.
2) "uploads" folder have to be constantly monitored, and with each new file added to him, a job has to be started.
3) Job will process data from .xls or .csv file so they meet DB table structure, and write this data into DB table.

This have to be automated process, and I'm looking for all-in-one solution tool.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't tell on which operating system, and you didn't tell if the user upload the files on a different server, or not. If the upload goes thru a web application (using an HTTP POST request), it is also different.

And I'm not sure that your wish scales well with many users.

Comment: In general OS makes no difference. I can put either on linux or windows. Users will upload files on same server, there will be only one server for uploaded files. As far as protocol for upload concern, it should be HTTP POST thru web app.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at Pentaho Data Integration, a.k.a. Kettle: http://sourceforge.net/projects/pentaho/

With Kettle you can desing a Job that pools the upload directory and once a file is found makes all the needed transformation and input on the desired database table.